# Renaming gradle apk output file, but there are 2 apks

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to name my application's APK file based on the git branch, which is working by passing a parameter in with jenkins.  However, I end up with two APKs, and this is undesirable because one of the Gradle tasks I have uploads the APK to a distributed list.  The whole point of renaming this APK is so that people who receive it know exactly what branch they are seeing.

```
buildTypes {
    ...

    feature {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug

        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig)
        }

    }

    ...
}

...

def appendVersionNameVersionCode(variant, defaultConfig) {
    //check if staging variant
    if(variant.name == android.buildTypes.feature.name){
        def branch = hasProperty('branch') ? branch.replaceAll('origin/', '') : "UNKNOWN"
        def file = variant.packageApplication.outputFile
        def fileName = "myapp-FEATURE-" + branch + ".apk"
        variant.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(file.parent, fileName)
    }
}
```

Then the gradle command is invoked:

```
gradle assembleFeature --project-dir=/Path/To/myapp/ -Pbranch=origin/development
```

The two files that are generated from that are:

1. app-feature.apk
2. myapp-FEATURE-development.apk

File 1 is not desired, and I would ultimately want to rename that file, instead of generating a new file which is File 2.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, gradle always packages up 2 apks. One that is aligned, and one that isn't.

In order to rename the aligned apk file, I had to add this:

```
    if (variant.zipAlign) {
        newName = "myapp-FEATURE-" + branch + "-ALIGNED.apk"
        variant.outputFile = new File(file.parentFile, newName);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure it's variant.zipAlign and not output.zipAlign? Because property zipAlign on variant is giving me a property not found error on Android Studio/Gradle Version 1.0.0.

Comment: latest version of gradle has changed the property 'zipAlign' to 'zipAlignEnabled', so you need use variant.zipAlignEnabled to judge.

Comment: Android studio doesn't automatically find this apk and report "Local path doesn't exists" error.. I guess this is Android Studio bug or?